# Is it possible to color columns by class in R's datatable when class color is set to T instead of bold?

Tags: colors, names

Instead of
grp          x          y
            
1:     1 -1.4367205 -0.1169949

can you replace the column class (datatable.print.class=T) and instead color the columns by class? For example Green for num, red for int?

I think it will move a lot of people. I can color  for example, but not the column names.